# Grub: no such device

Tags: grub2

I had to reinstall Mint recently and after reinstalling, I get an error in GRUB:

```
error: no such device: 94cf97c7-aa0f-48d7-8c9f-42fd51dc1a1a
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I have tried a bunch of things, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows), with no luck. I also found a guide for using grub rescue, but the second command it wanted me to execute failed with something like `could not read filesystem`. I forget the exact error and I can't find that guide again.

Basically, I need to know how to figure out what my computer is looking for when it boots, and why GRUB is trying to find a device that isn't there.

Bootinfoscript results:

[With external plugged in](http://pastebin.com/MVL3KdAL)
[Without external plugged in](http://pastebin.com/AMGY2kZm)